# Your mac os x startup disk has no more space available for application memory

Tags: objective-c, instruments

So after running my Objective-C application for about 8 hours, eventually my machine WILL display this error message. But after 24 hours using Instruments, it has only completed about 1% of what the app can do in 8 hours without instruments.

My application basically takes input geometry and creates a navigational mesh.

My question: How can I figure out where my issue is? I'm sure somewhere in my application I'm requesting memory and never freeing it. I ran analyze, which found one leak, but not significant and I've fixed it.

I'm running Instruments right now for allocations/leaks but after 16 minutes I don't see anything glaring (I'm going to let it keep going).

Here is a snapshot of where it's at thus far: 
[image: Instruments]

Anyone have any ideas on how else I can debug this?  I'd like to be able to run this for about 20 hours so it can complete vs. it inevitably dying :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there's a leak? Could your algorithm simply generate data structures whose size exceeds the available virtual memory? A 64-bit program can *address* a truly staggering amount of memory, but that doesn't mean it can actually *allocate* arbitrarily large amounts. How big would you expect your data to get, roughly? How did you determine that?

Answer (score 9):

You be leaking the memory like a champ!

- turn on "only track live allocations" in the Allocations instrument
- turn on "track reference counting events" (or whatever it is called)
- re-run your session and sort by the "Overall Bytes" column
- start at the top, the most memory hungry allocation, and click through the little arrow to see where all those allocations are coming from, continue down the list...

It is a lot like Heapshot analysis and, thus, [this weblog article](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) I wrote a while ago might be helpful.

Comment: So I'm trying this method, and I've had it running for 23 hours and it has completed 14 out of the 1131 tasks it needs to complete.  Normally all 1131 tasks take about 20 minutes total.  Any suggestions on how to debug where it can actually complete all the tasks :/  Instruments is still running @ 100% CPU (out of 800%), but it just can't keep up I guess

Comment: Here is a link to the results so far: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15806454/dump/stackoverflow_instruments.png